# I need to create an xml file, from a csv file that doesnt save the first row as tags

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq

i am trying to write a program that converts csv to xml.
my xml saves the first row from my csv as tags before putting in data.i will paste my code and output for better understanding. Here is my code.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim source As String() = File.ReadAllLines("c:\Data\csvtoxmlTEST.CSV")
        Dim firstRow As Boolean = True
        Dim cust As XElement =
  <events>
      <%= From strs In source
          Let fields = Split(strs, ",")
          Select
<event EventIdentity=<%= fields(0) %>>
    <name><%= fields(1) %></name>
    <summary><%= fields(2) %></summary>
    <description><%= fields(3) %></description>
    <local-start-date-time><%= fields(4) %></local-start-date-time>
    <local-end-date-time><%= fields(5) %></local-end-date-time>
    <status><%= fields(11) %></status>
    <locations>
        <location>
            <name><%= fields(6) %></name>
            <location>
                <name><%= fields(7) %></name>
                <location>
                    <name><%= fields(8) %></name>
                </location>
            </location>
        </location>
    </locations>
    <categories>
        <category>
            <name><%= fields(9) %></name>
        </category>
    </categories>
    <custom-data><%= fields(10) %></custom-data>
</event>
      %>
  </events>
        cust.Save("c:\Data\csvtoxmlTEST.xml")

    End Sub

End Module
```

My output prints the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<events>
  <event EventIdentity="EventIdentity">
    <name>EventName</name>
    <summary>EventSummary</summary>
    <description>EventDescription</description>
    <local-start-date-time>EventStart</local-start-date-time>
    <local-end-date-time>EventEnd</local-end-date-time>
    <status>status</status>
    <locations>
      <location>
        <name>Location1_Name</name>
        <location>
          <name>Location2_Building</name>
          <location>
            <name>Location3_Room</name>
          </location>
        </location>
      </location>
    </locations>
    <categories>
      <category>
        <name>Category</name>
      </category>
    </categories>
    <custom-data>Department</custom-data>
  </event>
  <event EventIdentity="17057">
    <name>ACCT</name>
    <summary> Financial Acct</summary>
    <description>ACCT 23071 Financial Acct</description>
    <local-start-date-time>1/28/2019 10:00AM</local-start-date-time>
    <local-end-date-time>1/28/2019 10:50AM</local-end-date-time>
    <status>A</status>
    <locations>
      <location>
        <name>TestClass</name>
        <location>
          <name>West</name>
          <location>
            <name>room - 24</name>
          </location>
        </location>
      </location>
    </locations>
    <categories>
      <category>
        <name>Academic Course</name>
      </category>
    </categories>
    <custom-data>School of Business Administration</custom-data>
  </event>
</events>
```

i want it to save my xml and start with `<event EventIdentity="17057">`, instead of `<event EventIdentity="EventIdentity">`.

Finally here is my test csv file that the program reads:
EventIdentity,EventName,EventSummary,EventDescription,EventStart,EventEnd,Location1_Name,Location2_Building,Location3_Room,Category,Department,status
17057,ACCT, Financial Acct,ACCT 23071 Financial Acct,1/28/2019 10:00AM,1/28/2019 10:50AM,TestClass,West,room - 24,Academic Course,School of Business Administration,A

Comment: `From strs In source.Skip(1)`

Comment: Great   Thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to `Skip` the first row. `source` is an array of strings - just skip the first item when you iterate it:

```
  <%= From strs In source.Skip(1)
      Let fields = Split(strs, ",")
      Select
  ...
```

Comment: Great   Thank you so much